# getting result set into DTO with native SQL Query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, native-sql, resulttransformer

I have a query like below

```
select f.id, s.name, ss.name
from first f
left join second s on f.id = s.id
left join second ss on f.sId = ss.id
```

If I could use HQL, I would have used [HQL constructor syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) to directly populate DTO with the result set.
But, since hibernate doesn't allow left join without having an association in place I have to use the Native SQL Query.

Currently I am looping through the result set in JDBC style and populating DTO objects.
Is there any simpler way to achieve it?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could maybe use a result transformer. Quoting [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/):

> #### SQL Transformers
>
> With native sql returning non-entity
>   beans or Map's is often more useful
>   instead of basic `Object[]`. With
>   result transformers that is now
>   possible.
>
> ```
> List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createSQLQuery(
>   "SELECT st.name as studentName, co.description as courseDescription " +
>   "FROM Enrolment e " +
>   "INNER JOIN Student st on e.studentId=st.studentId " +
>   "INNER JOIN Course co on e.courseCode=co.courseCode")
>   .addScalar("studentName")
>   .addScalar("courseDescription")
>   .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class))
>   .list();
>
> StudentDTO dto =(StudentDTO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
> ```
>
> Tip: the `addScalar()` calls were
>   required on HSQLDB to make it match a
>   property name since it returns column
>   names in all uppercase (e.g.
>   "STUDENTNAME"). This could also be
>   solved with a custom transformer that
>   search the property names instead of
>   using exact match - maybe we should
>   provide a fuzzyAliasToBean() method ;)

#### References

- Hibernate Reference Guide

  - [16.1.5. Returning non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904)
- Hibernate's Blog

  - [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pascal as always. :)

Comment: @PascalThivent How to do this if I want to fetch course description into an object inside StudentDTO (StudentDTO.CourseDTO.description)?

Comment: This should be inside the DTO class or a separated class?

Comment: Result transformer is deprecated.