# Can I use hibernate query language for entities not mapped to a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

Following is the mySQL query that I am using to retrieve `HolidayPackages for a given Hotel`:

```
SELECT 
    pkg.idHolidayPackage, pkg.name
FROM
    holidaypackage pkg
        INNER JOIN
    holidaypackagehotel hph ON pkg.idHolidayPackage = hph.idHolidayPackage
        INNER JOIN
    hotelroom hr ON hr.idHotelRoom = hph.idHotelRoom
WHERE
    hr.idHotel = 1;
```

I have POJOs with mapping for:

- HolidayPackage
- Hotel
- HotelRoom

I don't have a POJO for `HolidayPackageHotel`.

> Is there any way to use Criteria API or HQL to execute the sql query without creating a POJO for HolidayPackageHotel?

For the curios, DB relations:
[image: DB relations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. **You can not use the un-mapped entities inside the HQL**.

If you want to generate the List of beans from the query you can use the **ResultSet transformers, which can convert the query results(object arrays) to beans**. By doing this you  will save the overhead of creating and filling the POJO beans.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937519/507864) for an example.

Comment: I used the following NamedNativeQuery: @NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "getHolidayPackageForHotel", 
  query = "SELECT * FROM  wah_schema.holidaypackage pkg INNER JOIN wah_schema.holidaypackagehotel hph ON pkg.idHolidayPackage = hph.idHolidayPackage  INNER JOIN wah_schema.hotelroom hr ON hr.idHotelRoom = hph.idHotelRoom  WHERE hr.idHotel = :idHotel",
  resultClass= HolidayPackage.class)

This seemed to work for me, since the return type: HolidayPackage.class is a POJO entity I have defined. Do you think this approach has any drawbacks ?

Comment: In any query, **SELECT * from** is not a preferred approach. Add the column names in the select clause if possible. the rest is fine.

Comment: I get a **Column 'IDHOTELROOM' not found** if I use this: 

SELECT DISTINCT pkg.idHolidayPackage, pkg.name, pkg.itineraryHeader  FROM  wah_schema.holidaypackage pkg INNER JOIN wah_schema.holidaypackagehotel hph ON pkg.idHolidayPackage = hph.idHolidayPackage  INNER JOIN wah_schema.hotelroom hr ON hr.idHotelRoom = hph.idHotelRoom  WHERE hr.idHotel = ?

Comment: If you are running in to problems with **NamedNativeQuery** You can try the example given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3937519/507864).

Answer (score -3):

yes, You can use the un-mapped entities inside the HQL.Below is the example what i did in one of my project.

```
List list = session.createQuery("select p, a from UserAccount p, Channels a " +  "where p.uid = a.uid").list();  

Iterator iter = list.iterator();  
while (iter.hasNext())  
{  
  Object[] objArray = (Object[]) iter.next();  
  UserAccount p = (UserAccount) objArray[0];  
  Channels a = (Channels) objArray[1];  
  System.out.println(p.getUsername());  
  System.out.println(a.getTitle());  
}
```