# Is it possible to use HQL for Non-Mapped Entities

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

After Searching stack overflow I came to this
[Can I use hibernate query language for entities not mapped to a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782303/can-i-use-hibernate-query-language-for-entities-not-mapped-to-a-table) 
But recently I was making a small project where the two entities were not mapped by any Mapped Annotations and still I got the result for the query.
So I am confused as the posts say it is not possible to query on Non-Mapped Entities.

Customer

```
package com.mayank.bitmesra.pojo;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Customer {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String customerId;

    private String name;

    private String phoneNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    //for rolling back of Data
    //using date as such of now 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date updatedOn;


    //for picking up only the data that is most recent 
    //like a customer can have save with same customer id 
    //but has different address as his address might have changed up in near future 
    //will try to handle this  in near future
/*  @Temporal 
    private Date lastPickedUpDate;*/


    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + "]";
    }

    public Date getUpdatedOn() {
        return updatedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

     @PrePersist
      protected void onCreate() {
         createdDate = new Date();
      }

     @PreUpdate
      protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedOn = new Date();
      }



}
```

OrderDetails

```
package com.mayank.bitmesra.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class OrderDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String customerId;

    private String orderId;

    private String orderName;

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getOrderName() {
        return orderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }


}
```

OrderDetailsDAOImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class OrderDetailsDAOImpl implements OrderDetailsDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @Override
    public List getAllOrderDetails() {
//      return entityManager.createQuery("Select order from OrderDetails order ").getResultList();
    return entityManager.createQuery("Select customer.name from OrderDetails order inner join Customer customer on order.customerId=customer.customerId").getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: I think you are confused between hibernate mapping and SQL mapping. Since your entity classes are annotated with @Entity, they are mapped. This can also be done using xml files. By mapping you meant one to one or any other association. Which can be done by adding required configuration either by annotations or xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused . **@Entity** is the annotation used by HQL to identify the so called mapped entities. Both of the entities are annotated by them.