# Hibernate HQL - query.list() return Object array of object arrays

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate

I'm writing a HQL query. Depending on conditions in my view I'm adding selects in `SELECT` clause(the number of selects is from 1 to about 20). Using `list()` on query hibernate will return **Object array of object arrays** at least I think so. If I iterate trough the result

```
 Iterator<Object[]> itr = result.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
               Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
               System.out.println(obj);                        //1st
               for (int br = 0; br <= obj.length-1;br ++) {
                   System.out.print(obj[br].toString() + ","); //2nd
               }
            }
```

The 1st `Sytsem.out prints` each Object array and the 2nd one prints their's content. For testing output to console is fine.

I try to use the results to Jasper Reports and somehow can't access the content of each Object array. Can someone give me advice or suggest an approach like converting the results to format I can use in report.

Comment: Put your `Jasper Report` code here.

Comment: `JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(result);
     JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(pathToReport);
     
     JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
     
     JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, beanColDataSource);`

Answer (score 2):

JRBeanCollectionDataSource supposes collection of beans - POJO classes. Then it tries to find proper field of the class by Jasper report's field name.

Thus if in Jasper Report your define a field 'userName' the JRBeanCollectionDataSource gets POJO class and tries to find the class' field 'userName'.

In your case instead of POJO class you get array Object[]. So can't find the field called 'userName'.

I suggest to define DTO (Data transfer object) and convert the Object[] to the DTO. Thus you will have List and the JRBeanCollectionDataSource can resolve proper names.

A simple way is to define results transformer.

```
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(ResultsDTO.class))
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937131/getting-result-set-into-dto-with-native-sql-query-in-hibernate)

Comment: Yes, this will be the usual way  I approach this, but here because my `SELECT` clause change depending on conditions, I do not know the number of fields I need to declare in the DTO.

Comment: You can use JRMapCollectionDataSource (list of maps). Just create a way to convert the Object[] to Map<String, Object> where String is the key must correspond the jasper report field name.

Comment: If I do it this way the number of fields in jasper report will be equal to number of objects my query return. My query will return variable number of objects so I don't know how to generate fields in jasper dynamical. Or I'm wrong

Comment: On my research of the problem found suggestions using CG lib or Javassist but it's a approach I've never used before.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. Your jasper reprot has some fixed fields (fixed names). You somehow should get the collection of field names and you have to create list of maps (one map for each row. Each the map should have as many key/value pairs as field names obtained from jasper.