# How to get the data in query(search result of hql)?

Tags: hql, hibernate-entitymanager

I am a novice to use `jdbc` and I have some problems.

I use hql to search data in MySQL, and the result is `Query` type. I don't know how to get the data from the "Query".This is my code:

```
final String hql = "select app.appkey,app.type from " + getClassName() +
 "app where app.appkey<>'no-appkey' group by app.type";
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: third line: query.list();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting a list of results, so:

```
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

If you are expect one single result:

```
Object[] result = query.getSingleResult(); // if more than one result was found, this method will throw a NonUniqueResultException
```

If column information will be stored in a position of the Object array. Example:

```
String appKey = (String) result[0];
String appType = (String) result[1];
```

But work with Object array is not good. Try to use Dto, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993647/2387977).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

```
final String hql = "select app.appkey,app.type from " + getClassName() + " app where app.appkey<>'no-appkey' group by app.type";
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql);
query.list(); //or query.getSingleResult();
```

`query.list()` will give a list of results.

`query.getSingleResult()` will give you a object.

You can check [this.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)

Comment: Thanks! I use this method and get the object. But how can I get data in the object? This is my code:           ```for (RequestLog list:lists){
                System.out.println(list.getAppKey());
                System.out.println(list.getType());
        }```     It is wrong, exception is "can not cast Object to RequestLog(RequestLog is the JavaBean)".